# e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, edit

I'm trying to get my edit button to work as well as my delete button, but it gives me the following error message in the console "e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.setAttribute is not a function".

this is the code I'm trying to add for my edit functionality,
I have found a similar issue, but it didn't solve the problem I have

```
const editBtn = document.createElement("button");
    editBtn.classList.add("edit");
    editBtn.textContent = "Edit";
    newLi.appendChild(editBtn);

    editBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {});
    document.querySelector("*").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      
      if (e.target.className !== "edit") return;
      
      e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.setAttribute(
        "contenteditable",
        "true"
      );
     
      e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.focus();
    });
```

Comment: what do you expect document.querySelector("*")  to be exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that there are empty text elements between your elements

Use `previousElementSibling` intead

Comment: Getting this now
Uncaught TypeError: e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling is null